# Type casting error while using couchbase

Tags: c#, types, casting, error-handling, couchbase

I have a view named "TotalPosts" in my couchbase data bucket. The design document name is "Statistics".

This is my code. I am establishing the connection over here..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
              {
                var client= new CouchbaseClient();
                Tasks objTasks = new Tasks();
        foreach (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken jt in objTasks.GetAllStatistics())
        {
            if (jt["key"].ToString() == "Total")
            {
                dt.Rows[0]["Value"] = jt["value"].ToString();
            }
            if (jt["key"].ToString() == "Open")
            {
                dt.Rows[1]["Value"] = jt["value"].ToString();
            }
            if (jt["key"].ToString() == "Wah")
            {
                dt.Rows[2]["Value"] = jt["value"].ToString();
            }

        }
```

This is my GetAllStatistics function definition code:

```
public IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> GetAllStatistics()
        {

            var results = oCouchbase.GetView("Statistics", "TotalPosts");
            return results;// I am getting the following error in this line
        }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'Couchbase.IView' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my map code:

```
function(doc) {
emit("Total", 1);
    emit("TotalParticipants", doc.participants.length);
    if(doc.status == "1"){
        emit("Open", 1);
    } else if(doc.status == "2") {
        emit("Wah", parseInt(doc.wah_points));
    }
}
```

This is my reduce code:

```
function (key, values, rereduce) {
    return sum(values);
}
```

I could not find an appropriate type casting. Kindly help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

I can't claim any knowledge of Couchbase, but the error message indicates that you can perform an explicit cast.  Have you tried just doing a cast for your return?

```
return (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)results;
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-generic version of GetView returns an enumerable list of IViewRow.  So instead, I would recommend changing your GetAllStatistics method to something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken> GetAllStatistics()
{
    var results = oCouchbase.GetView("Statistics", "TotalPosts");
    foreach(var row in results)
    {
        yield return oCouchbase.Get<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(row.ItemId);
    }
}
```

Then your foreach loop should work as is.  However, a question I have is what your documents look like.  Are you serializing JToken instances as the value in your Store operations?  If you are, then they will not be available in your views as only valid JSON strings will be usable within a view.  If you have any questions about anything I just mentioned, please feel free to edit your question to include your Store operations and the map/reduce view code.

Comment: I have included the map and reduce code.. Kindly check that.. I have tried the way u mentioned above but it is throwing an exception
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."